# Use custom marker when specific checkbox is checked

Tags: 7, views, location, google-maps

I am building an events page. The page is using Gmap, Locations and Views modules.

In the content type "Events", I have set a checkbox for "Featured Event", I want these events to stand out in the map, so I would like to use a different marker in the map if the event is a "Featured Event".

Please let me know how to do this. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I would use CSS for this.

- Add your featured checkbox field
- Add a `views-row` class, in the format settings, with the replacement pattern of the value for the checkbox

Now I can't remember if GMap will add that class to the marker rows too. If it does not, I would advise you to override the template for the view and in the class section, add `$fields['field_featured']`, making sure that there is a space before it

- Using that class, you can style it however you want using CSS and/or JS

Hope that helps!

Comment: Sounds like a great idea, thanks for the post. I will try this and get back to you.

Comment: There is no way to add a class to gmap marker row, could you help please? this is the html that I am seeing:

<div style="width: 20px; height: 34px; overflow: hidden; position: absolute; opacity: 0.01; cursor: pointer; left: 1080px; top: 375px; z-index: 392;" class="gmnoprint" title=""><img style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; -moz-user-select: none; border: 0px none; padding: 0px; margin: 0px; max-width: none; width: 20px; height: 34px;" src="/sites/all/modules/gmap/markers/event.png" draggable="false"></div>

Comment: I fixed this issue with the help of the "GMap Taxonomy Markers" module. Thanks for your time.